# Combinatorics summation problem - $\sum_{k=0}^r k.{n \choose k}. {m \choose {c-k}} = ?$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, combinations, binomial-coefficients

Is there any way to calculate this - $$\sum_{k=0}^r k.{n \choose k}. {m \choose {c-k}}$$ where $r, n, m$ and $c$ are constants and $k \leq c$.

I have no idea how to approach this.

Thanks!

**EDIT** - To be more specific I actually need to calculate this - $$\sum_{k=0}^{150} k.{1000 \choose k}. {14000 \choose {150-k}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the pmf of a hypergeometric distribution with parameters $N=15000,K=1000,n=150$ is given by $$p(k)=\frac{\binom{1000}{k}\binom{14000}{150-k}}{\binom{15000}{150}}$$
and the expected value is $$\sum _{k=0}^{150}k\cdot \frac{\binom{1000}{k}\binom{14000}{150-k}}{\binom{15000}{150}}=n\cdot \frac{K}{N}=150\cdot \frac{1000}{15000}=10$$
Multiplying both sides by $\binom{15000}{150}$, $$\sum_{k=0}^{150}k\cdot \binom{1000}{k}\binom{14000}{150-k}=10\binom{15000}{150}$$

Comment: Oh, ok, I completely forgot about that distribution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you actually have $c = r$, which simplifies the problem considerably.

Basically, it allows you to use the fact that
$$ \binom{n+m}{x} = \sum_{k=0}^{x} \binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{x-k}.$$
The only problem is getting your original expression in this form in the first place.

To do so, note that
$$ k\binom{n}{k} = k\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = n\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!((n-1)-(k-1)!)} = n\binom{n-1}{k-1}. $$

Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{r} k \binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{r-k}
   &= \sum_{k=1}^{r} k \binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{r-k} \\
   &= \sum_{k=1}^{r} n\binom{n-1}{k-1}\binom{m}{(r-1)-(k-1)} \\
   &= \sum_{s=0}^{r-1} n \binom{n-1}{s}\binom{m}{(r-1)-s} \\
   &= n\binom{m+n-1}{r-1}.
\end{align*}

Also, for completeness I should point out that this is consistent with DerpShady's answer -- in terms of this notation, their answer is
$$ r \frac{n}{n + m} \binom{m+n}{r}. $$